# 301 redirect to new domain with same url structure

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a Magento website that is moving to a new domain. Im looking to 301 redirect all pages from the old domain to the new domain keeping same url structure.

I've updated the .htaccess file on my old domain with:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**The issue:** The above seems to redirect every instance of: `old-domain.com/subdir/whatever` only just to the main domain: `new-domain.com`.

I'd be looking to redirect `old-domain.com/subdir/whatever` to: `new-domain.com/subdir/whatever`.

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjust your rule to use `REQUEST_URI` variable which is not dependent on the directory of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Better to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

**PS:** You need to match hostname condition to old-host not the new-host.

Answer (score 3):

This should redirect and retain the path after the main domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Adam - just as a reference this also worked out very fine. Though anubhava pointed out my main issue - that I had the wrong HTTP_HOST defined. Thanks a lot for contributing though